# how to build a .c file in sublime text 3

Tags: c, sublimetext3

i just started learning c. i want to learn doing it in sublime text unlike any IDE. so when i tried to build my .c file in sbt3, i am receiving the following error

```
clang: error: no input files
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: g++ "" -o "/"]
[dir: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

i have no idea what that is. i am a newbie to everything.i have tried some solutions that i found online like creating a new build system. but it ain't helping. Could someone help me with what's going on here?

Comment: Update your post with the contents of your build system file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to a gist of your build-file.

You can see also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767409/how-to-run-and-compile-c-on-sublime-text-2-mac-os-x). It is for sublime text 2, but I think it should cover you.